# Data that is not found is not triggering the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const roblox = require("noblox.js");
const RobloxDB = require("../models/roblox.js");
const ModLogDB = require("../models/modlog.js");

    ModLogDB.find({
        offenderID:ID 
    },(err,data)=>{
        if(err) console.log(err);
        if(data){
            var TotalActions = 0
            data.forEach(Act=>{
                if(TotalActions >= 5){
                  return;
                }
                TotalActions = TotalActions + 1
                message.channel.send("**Sanction Type:** ${Act.sanctionType} | **Sanction ID:** ${Act.sanctionID} - **Sanction Reason:** ${Act.sanctionReason}")
            })

        }        
        if(!data){
            message.channel.send("**History Clear** - There are no records for that user!")
            return;
        }

    })
```

The part of the code where `if(!data)` the message is not sending.
I have logged from where it says console.log and have also logged the data not found area and have found that the no data found side is not printing, why might this be?

Comment: Could you console.log data right after the error handling? That way you can see the data in both cases, maybe its not false when you expect it to be. Also you could replace ‘if(!data){‘ with a simpler ‘else’

Comment: Either `if(data)` or `if(!data)` must be executing. But I agree that using `else` would be clearer.